# What's this white box visible in the Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

This weird box keeps showing up. Looks like the only thing open is finder, can't imagine what else would be 'running' it.

[image: jij]

What is this thing?

Comment: is it to do with keyboard inputs?

Comment: Please add your system version and edit your question instead of commenting it with further details/questions!

Comment: Could it be the Edit > Show Clipboard window? What happens if you do Mission Control (⌃↑)?

Comment: I am having the same problem right now. Do you figure out what it is and how to close it?! thanks a lot.

Comment: OK. This THING is really weird. But the good part is It will disappear after I logout and re-login. So, it's fine now.

Comment: @sgon00 it’s something to do with IME keyboards I think.

Comment: @user3306356 ok, cheers. I hope someone can answer this question and explain clearly what the thing is. :)